# how to convert json into pojo where no param name is given

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I am trying to convert JSON to java using Jackson. But not getting proper solution. I have JSON which does not have parameter name in it. I want to use PropertyOrder to map json fields to POJO.

I tried type reference in all possible ways but failed to get my desired result.

My JSON is like :
{"1222": ["Joe", 26, 158],"1232": ["root", 29, 168] }

Below are the pojo:

```
public class Employee{
    int empId;
    EmployeeAtttribute employeeAttribute;
}

@JsonProertyOrder({"name", "seq", "height"})  
public class EmployeeAttribute{     
    String name;  
    int seq;  
    int height;  
}
```

I am looking to get List of Employee class made using JSON.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I tried:                                                                                                       
 ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();                        Map<String, Object> jsonMap = objectMapper.readValue(readFile(pathToJsonFile),
      new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>(){});

Comment: Well `@JsonPropertyOrder` is used to define the order of properties when serializing the pojo, i.e. when generating the json. It's not applicable to your case. I'm not aware of any annotation based way to define that mapping so you might have to do it yourself, e.g. via a custom deserializer.

Comment: Don't put the code you tried in comments, [edit] the post and put it there.

Comment: Thanks  for your input. Please have look on the response given by TechFree. It worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotate EmployeeAttribute class as:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
@JsonPropertyOrder({"name", "seq", "height"})
public class EmployeeAttribute
{

    public String name;

    public int seq;

    public int height;

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "EmployeeAttribute [name=" + name + ", seq=" + seq + ", height=" + height + "]";
    }
}
```

You can use this code to convert your JSON to Object (map):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonInput = "{\"1222\": [\"Joe\", 26, 158],\"1232\": [\"root\", 29, 168] }";
TypeReference<Map<String, EmployeeAttribute>> typeRef =
    new TypeReference<Map<String, EmployeeAttribute>>()
    {
    };

Map<String, EmployeeAttribute> map = mapper.readValue(jsonInput, typeRef);
map.values().iterator().forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```

Further convert this to a list of Employee:

```
 List<Employee> employee = new ArrayList<>();
 for (Map.Entry<String, EmployeeAttribute> entry : map.entrySet()) {
       employee.add(new Employee(Integer.valueOf(entry.getKey()), 
  entry.getValue()));
 }
```

To the extended requirement where the input JSON string contained 'emp_count' key, since the input is not really parseable to a Java Object model, this approach can be used which reads this element, and removes it, so that parsing as per the original logic would work as before and the 'emp_count' is still read/extracted. Optimize as required:

```
String jsonInput = "{\"1222\": [\"Joe\", 26, 158],\"1232\": [\"root\", 29, 168], \"emp_count\" : \"2\"}";
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(jsonInput);
if (node.has("emp_count")) {
   int employeesInArray = ((ObjectNode) node).remove("emp_count").asInt();
   System.out.println("Num of employees in array: " + employeesInArray);
} else {
   System.out.println("Num of employees was not provided, missing emp_count element");
}

//updated JSON input String, that works as before
jsonInput = node.toString();
```

Comment: Hello TechFree,                                                                                            
  {"1222": ["Joe", 26, 158],"1232": ["root", 29, 168], "emp_count" : "2"}                      in this case will your approach support. As I can see we have bound it value type to be Array in JsonFormat. what if I want to ignore or use emp_count (both cases). Could you please share your thoughts on this.

Comment: I will update the answer with this extended requirement

Answer (score 1):

Your json will be parsed as `Map<String, List<Object>>`.
After that you can convert `Map<String, List<Object>>` to your Employee or change json format. `{"id":1222, "attribute":{"name":"Joe", "seq":26, "height": 158}}`

Comment: Thanks  for your input. Please have look on the response given by TechFree. It worked.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer,specially if you're using maping library